SSRS Subreport Fails When Dataset Is Added
I have a report that includes a subreport. The subreport has a simple dataset with one parameter. When I test the report, it shows "Error: Subreport could not be shown." I've done some troubleshooting and confirmed 1) the subreport runs correctly when run independently and 2) the parameter passes from the main report to the subreport correctly. The error appears to occur when the dataset is added to the subreport, and I can't figure out why. Here are the steps I followed for troubleshooting.
I removed the dataset and table from the subreport, so only the parameter remained. I placed a text box that displayed the parameter in the report so that I could confirm the parameter passed from the main report to the subreport.

I ran the main report. The yellow column is the KeyID from the main report that passes to the subreport. The Attachments column contains the subreport. Since the KeyID and Attachment columns match, the parameter is passing correctly.

I added the dataset to the report. And then confirmed the subreport runs without error.


I re-ran the main report with the dataset in the subreport, and now I get the error.

Any suggestions? Everything I've found online so far points towards the parameter not passing correctly, but that does not seem to be the issue here.

Do you have Available Value set in your subreport? If so then remove that and test again. If that does not work, try hardcoding the parameter value that is passed from the main report to a value you know is good "KeyID=56285" for example and see what happens. Finally make sure the parameter is set to string.

@AlanSchofield Thanks for the troubleshooting tip. I'm not sure what technology magic is going on, but I tested by hard coding the value, and it worked. I then changed it back to passing the field from the main report and it still worked.!

That's random :) It may have been cached data. I don't use Report Builder, I use Visual Studio and if anything odd happens, the first thing I do is remove the .rdl.data file(s) as these cache previous results (same as doing a 'Clean project/solution'  in VS) but I'm not sure either of these is applicable to Report Builder.
